# Efeito do ajax no button

Tags: ajax, primefaces

No `commandButton` do `primefaces` temos u atributo `ajax` que pode ser `true` ou `false`. Qual o efeito dele em submissão ? Eu estou fazendo um exemplo bobo onde o usuário digita um nome e aciona o botão, logo após é exibido o nome digitado. Neste caso só funciona se o `ajax` estiver `false`, porque ?

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <p:outputLabel value="Nome" />
        <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{modelo.nome}"/> 
        <p:outputLabel id="resultado" styleClass="data" rendered="#{!empty modelo.nome}" value="#{modelo.nome}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton id="su" value="Salvar" update="resultado" ajax="false"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A opção "ajax" basicamente diz se vai haver um *submit* da página quando a ação do botão for disparada e consequentemente a nova renderização de todos os seus componentes. 
No teu caso, o *update* seria usado para renderizar novamente o `outputLabel` sem submeter a página toda, mas não está funcionando porque esse componente tem uma condição `rendered`. O que acontece é que o atributo *update* deveria apontar para um id de um componente existente no DOM. Como esse elemento não está renderizado no lado do servidor, nenhum componente é encontrado para ser atualizado. Uma forma de resolver esse problema é criar um outro componente que circunde o `outputLabel` e atualizar esse componente, já que ele não vai ter condição de renderização e portanto vai existir no DOM:

```xml
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <p:outputLabel value="Nome" />
    <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{modelo.nome}"/> 
    <h:panelGroup id="panel">
       <p:outputLabel id="resultado" styleClass="data" rendered="#{!empty modelo.nome}" value="#{modelo.nome}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <p:commandButton id="su" value="Salvar" update="panel"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Agora, atualizando o `panelGroup` teu botão vai funcionar com o AJAX.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. Show